# compare date types using between

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

below is a query I am running to get all the accounts with a locate date not between the date of the transaction and transaction date - 60. When I run it, the query returns this rows that are incorrect. When looking into this problem I made sure all dates are of the same time (they are all defined as `date`, not `timestamp`).

Edit: I have also tried putting the dates in `trunc()` and `to_date()` to no avail.

Here are the values of the dates that I am receiving:

```
skip_locate           :22-AUG-13
transaction_date      :30-AUG-13
transaction_date - 60 :01-JUL-13
```

EDIT 2: For those wondering about the dates, and if they are really from 2013:

```
skip_locate           :2013-08-22 00:00:00
transaction_date      :2013-08-30 00:00:00
transaction_date - 60 :2013-07-01 00:00:00
```

Also as I was playing around, when I take away the `NOT` in the `NOT BETWEEN` I get no results. This is wrong due to the fact that skip_locate is in fact between the two dates.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rl.complaint_date, 
                  rl.complaint_amt, 
                  rl.date_served1, 
                  rl.date_served2,
                  rl.judgement_date,         
                  rl.skip_locate,                       
                  lcc.bal_range_min, 
                  lcc.bal_range_max, 
                  lcc.cost_range_min, 
                  lcc.cost_range_max, 
                  lcc.court, 
                  ah.ACCOUNT, 
                  ah.transaction_code, 
                  ah.transaction_date,
                  ah.transaction_date - 60 "t - 60",
                  ah.rule_id, 
                  ah.amount, 
                  ah.description,                      
                  r.state, 
                  r.zip_code, 
                  z.county                      
  FROM racctrel r, 
       ziplist z, 
       legal_court_cost lcc, 
       racctlgl rl,
       legal_transaction_review ah
  WHERE substr(r.zip_code,1,5) = z.zip
  AND r.state = lcc.state
  AND REPLACE(lcc.county,' ','') = REPLACE(upper(z.county),' ','')
  AND r.ACCOUNT = rl.ACCOUNT
  AND r.ACCOUNT = ah.ACCOUNT
  AND lcc.transaction_code = ah.transaction_code
  AND lcc.transaction_code in (2,31)
  AND lcc.end_date IS NULL
  AND ah.batch_id = 257
  and rl.skip_locate not between ah.transaction_date and ah.transaction_date - 60;
```

Comment: are you trying to exclude `skip_locate           :22-AUG-13` or include it? what is the output you have and would like?

Comment: I would like to exclude it because it is between the transaction date and transaction date - 60.

`and rl.skip_locate not between ah.transaction_date and ah.transaction_date - 60;`

Comment: In addition to @mrtig's questions, are you sure that the year on your dates is what you expect?  You're only displaying a 2 digit year in your post.  Are you certain that those dates are all 2013 rather than 1913 or 0013?  It's relatively common for developers to use the wrong format mask to convert strings in a front end into dates in the database and end up with dates in the wrong century.

Comment: You stated that the query returns rows that should not be returned.  What are the values of rl.skip_locate and  ah.transaction_date for these rows?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes I am sure that the dates are 2013. The system that I am working on only started receiving data around May or so.

Comment: @DanBracuk The values that are coming out are posted at the top of the question.

Comment: @user2405778 - The fact that the system is new has no bearing on what century the dates actually are.  I've seen plenty of cases where bugs were caused by dates that were 2000 years off of what was expected because of programming bugs (i.e. using incorrect format masks on the front end).  Obviously, those systems haven't been around gathering data for 2000+ years.

Comment: @JustinCave Well I look at all the data being imported into the table that I am checking. They are all from 2013. When I change it to 
`and rl.skip_locate > ah.transaction_date - 60` it works fine. I came here to figure out the problem so I can learn from it rather then just ignoring it an moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a BETWEEN predicate you place the earliest value first and the latest one second, so the code should be:

```
... BETWEEN ah.transaction_date - 60 and ah.transaction_date
```

If you had two dates and were not sure which was earliest and which latest, you would:

```
... BETWEEN Least(date_1, date_2) and Greatest(date_1, date_2)
```

Comment: Wow you learn something new everyday. Thank you very much for taking the time and answering my question.